# How do I update the locations of multiple markers in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, marker

I am using google maps api to place markers on a map. The gps coordinates of the markers are stored in a mySQL database. I have been able to create the markers however the locations will constantly changing so I was wondering how I would go about updating the markers' locations so that the markers will move across the map. Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Map</title>
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.9947935, -122.0622702);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);



    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('busIcon.png',
        // The image size
        new google.maps.Size(44, 46),
        // The origin
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        // The anchor
        new google.maps.Point(22, 23));

    var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('busIcon_shadow.png',
        new google.maps.Size(58, 46),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(22, 23)
    ); 

    var shape = {
        coord: [1, 1, 1, 45, 43, 45, 43 , 1],
        type: 'poly'
    };
    var markers = [

        <?php

        // Make a MySQL Connection
        mysql_connect("**********", "**********", "**********") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("matsallen") or die(mysql_error());

        //Get number of rows
        $result = mysql_query
        (
            'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM busTrack AS count'
        )
        or die(mysql_error());

        $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

        $length = $row["COUNT(*)"];
        for ($count = 1; $count <= $length; $count++) {


            //Get data from MySQL database
            $result = mysql_query
            (
                'SELECT * FROM busTrack WHERE busID = '.$count
            )
            or die(mysql_error());




            // store the record of the "busTrack" table into $row
            $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

            // Echo the data into the array 'markers'

            $output = '{id: "Bus '.$row[busID].'", lat: '.$row[lat].', lng: '.$row[lon].'}';
            if ($count != $length) {
                $output = $output.',';
            };
            echo $output;
        };


        ?>

    ];

    for (index in markers) addMarker(map, markers[index]);



  function addMarker(map, data) {
    //create the markers
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
        map: map,
        title: data.id,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        shadow: shadow
    });

    //create the info windows
    var content = document.createElement("DIV");
    var title = document.createElement("DIV");
    title.innerHTML = data.id;
    content.appendChild(title);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: content
    });

    // Open the infowindow on marker click
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });


  }
}



</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:75%; height:75%; margin:10%; allign:center;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to just change the location of a marker whenever you get a new location for it?  Or are you hoping to animate the marker so it slides smoothly across the map?  The former will be easier than the latter, of course.

Comment: the former would work but the latter is preferable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the location of a marker, call setPosition() on that marker:

```
marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(newLat,newLng);
```

To do this, you will need to save all your markers in an array.  Perhaps something like this would work:

```
var myMarkers = new Array();
for (index in markers) {
    myMarker[ markers[index]['id'] ] = addMarker(map, markers[index]);
}

function addMarker(map, data) {
    //create the markers
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
        map: map,
        title: data.id,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        shadow: shadow
    });

    //create the info windows
    var content = document.createElement("DIV");
    var title = document.createElement("DIV");
    title.innerHTML = data.id;
    content.appendChild(title);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: content
    });

    // Open the infowindow on marker click
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    return marker;    
}
```

Then, when the position of a marker needs to change, hopefully you know the bus ID and can just call:

```
myMarkers['Bus 47'].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(newLat,newLng);
```

I didn't test the above code so there may be small syntax errors or something, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: im still not sure how you would use setPosition to update the location of **each** marker. Are all of the markers for the map stored in an array that i could access? Would you mind giving me an example?

Comment: OK, I fleshed out the answer considerably.

Comment: On very huge set of markers this approach still causes problems like browser not responding and ultimately crashing down. We have this issue with one of our clients who has lots of units showing/updating via GPS in real time, but after sometime browser stops responding and then crashes down. No solution yet I found.