# Adding Multiple markers upon receiving new information

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

newbie here.
I'm working on a program that display the postion of vehicles on a map. #Google Maps API V3.
The program will automatically receive information like longitude, latitude, speed, date etc from sql server (live). I want the map to display all the markers( long & lat available) and update the position of markers each time the position of that specific marker changes. The update including the infowindows for each marker. My problem is no marker is shown on the map upon starting the program(lat & long received). Below are the code :

```
    var map = null;
    var Table_Pins = {};     // Liste des Pins affichées
    var Pos_Info = null;     // Dit sur quel marker se situe l'infobulle
    var Liste_Points = []; // Pour la mémorisation du tracé
    var route = null;
    var markers = [];

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.665, 7.052),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, //Type de carte
                mapTypeControl: true,
                panControl: true,
                zoomControl: true, //Zoom
                scaleControl: true, //Echelle
                scaleControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM},
                streetViewControl: true
                } ;
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
            Affiche_Pin(map, myPin);
            }
            //------------------------
            // Ouverture du WebBrowser
            // -----------------------
        try { google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);}
        catch (ex){ alert("vous devez etre connecte a l'internet...");}


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //                          Affichage des véhicules
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var myPin =[];
    function Affiche_Pin(Lat, Long, immat, type, site, vitesse, date)
    { 

       myPin = Table_Pins[immat];


    if (typeof myPin != "undefined") 
     {
     myPin.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Long))
      // La Pin est déja placée, on la déplace
      // -------------------------------------
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map')); 
       map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Long));
       map.setZoom(15);
       map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);

       if (Pos_Info == myPin) {
       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content: myPin.html, 
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Long) });
       infowindow.open(map);
       } //end if (pos_info)
     }//end if (mypin)

     else{

     var imageMarqueur = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon15.png',
          new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
          new google.maps.Point(0,0),
          new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
     var ombreMarqueur = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon15s.png',
          new google.maps.Size(56, 32),
          new google.maps.Point(0,0),
          new google.maps.Point(16, 32));

     var vehlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Long) ;
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: map,
     position: vehlatlng,
     icon: imageMarqueur,
     shadow: ombreMarqueur       });

     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: 'Véhicule :' + immat + ' ' + '<br>' +
            'Site : ' + site + '<br>' +
            'Type : ' + type + '<br>' +
            'Vitesse : ' + vitesse + ' km/h' + '<br>' +
            'Date : ' + date + '<br>',  
     position: vehlatlng });
      }//end else

     // Evenement "Click" et "infowindowopen" du marker
     // ---------------------------
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          if(lastOpenInfoWin) lastOpenInfoWin.close();
          lastOpenInfoWin = infowindow;
          infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker); 
          Pos_Info = marker;});

    Table_Pins[immat] = marker;

      markers.push(marker);
     marker.setMap(map);


  }//end function affiche_pin
```

"immat" is the id of vehicle,
"vitesse" is speed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I update the locations of multiple markers in google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121733/how-do-i-update-the-locations-of-multiple-markers-in-google-maps)

Comment: it's quick similar but not the same. I don't use php. Instead the map is open in a VB program that connect to server automatically upon open the program. I tried following the guide from that suggestion but stil fail to find what i'm missing. Any one please help!!!

Comment: Duplicate of [Google Maps API V3 Multiple Marker updated automatically when Lat & Long changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537358/google-maps-api-v3-multiple-marker-updated-automatically-when-lat-long-changes?noredirect=1#comment24203799_16537358)

Comment: if this is the real function you are using , it have some syntax errors. 
       position: vehlatlng }),    
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Long) });
I dont know why did u have two positions.

Comment: sorry about that, i corrected it, but still not working. More specific is i have stream of data from sql server where i need to show the marker of each position together with their infowindows when click. each time new data receive, new marker shown along with their infowindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's just a problem of global and local variance.Avoid defined var map in function when already defined var map = null in global. Only "map"is enough without "var" in a function.